# Update Table column fields from another table

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a excel tracker (let's call it 'Master File_1') that I need to send to my team, have each of them update his part and send their updates to me for consolidation.

Is there a solution that I can implement (either VBA or Power Query to do the following)?

1. Consolidate the individual trackers to obtain ('Master File_2')
2. Update only selected columns from 'Master File_2' into 'MasterFile_1'

Both master files will contain same number of columns and same positioning. There is also a unique identifier that I can link both with.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a new user here, please take a moment to learn [ask], then edit your question and post your code.

Comment: @teylyn - many thanks for your response. I went through the documentation you shared; however, I am not sure how I can edit my post. The issue is that I don't have a code as a starting point. I posted here so that I may get help with an initial code that I can test it out on my data to see if it responds to what I am looking for.